# Docker push to Docker Hub unauthorized Error on Mac

Tags: git, docker, docker-for-mac

I'm trying to push a docker image to my docker hub repository but it fails at **unauthorized : authentication required** even after successfully **docker login**.
What's wrong here? 
Help me, please!

Here's **Docker Image**:

[image: Here's arycloud is my username and istiofirst repository exists on my Docker Hub account]

Here's **Docker push**:
[image]

Here's my Docker **config.json**:
[image]

Comment: Go to you OSX keychains (through spotlight). Search for docker and delete all saved credentials under the `login` keychains. Delete the config.json and try to login again

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani , thanks it works!

Comment: Great, posted as answer, please accept

Answer (score 1):

Go to you OSX keychains (through spotlight). Search for docker and delete all saved credentials under the login keychains. Delete the config.json and try to login again

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with config.json file. Try to recreate config.json file

```
#find / -name config.json
#mv xxx/.docker/config.json  xxx/.docker/config_old.json
```

Then continue with these steps:

```
docker login https://index.docker.io/v1/
Username:
Password:
```